# regular expression to replace document.all.something with document.getElementById("something")

Tags: javascript, regex, getelementbyid

I have many old javascript files written for and IE project that I need to convert. They use `document.all.somename` instead of `document.getElementById("somename")`. I've been manually converting these and my hands are cramping up. Is there a way to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Wat? This doesn't seem to be a programming question. Open your favourite text editor and "find and replace".

Comment: Yes, there is -- have you done any research at all, or made any attempt?

Comment: What environment/editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capturing group to capture the `somename` part.

```
> "bar document.all.somename foo".replace(/\bdocument\.all\.(\w+)\b/g, 'document.getElementById("$1")')
'bar document.getElementById("somename") foo'
```

Comment: if the name contains only alphabets then use `[A-Za-z]+` instead `\w+`

Comment: If there are only alphabetic characters then either way will work. Some cases may have numbers or `_`, so they should use `\w+` just in case.

Comment: I could use this.  Thanks.  How would I use the group and regular expressions in a text editor like textmate or monodevelop?

Comment: Oh I got it. For textmate I just used find \bdocument\.all\.(\w+)\b regular expression with the replace you specified and it works great. Thanks,